# Execute testNG in CMD prompt

Tags: json, selenium-webdriver, gson, testng

Unable to execute testNG in CMD prompt.

I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonObject

I have all the `jar`s in my build path. `gson-2.8.2.jar` and all the selenium supported `jar`s and even testng `jar`s.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonObject Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonObject

Command used to run:

> java -cp bin;jarslib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

All the jars in my JarsLib folder

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the command line you are using to run your tests ? Also how does your project structure look like ? How are you managing your classpath ? Please edit your question and add all this information in there.

Comment: I found the solution, I've added into my resource but not added into my environment variable. Once I added, it's working fine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I've added into my resource but not added into my environment variable. Once I added, it's working fine.